# I want a screen positioned so I can use bifocals (lower portion).

Tags: display

I wear bifocals and can focus on both the computer screen and papers using the lower part of the lens. But, my screen is so high I have to hold my head up and get a stiff neck. Otherwise, I have to change glasses every time I shift from the computer to papers. Is there any way to lower the screen so it is at the same angle as I hold a book or paper to read?

Comment: Higher chair, lower table? Remove the screen from the stand and place it horizontally?

Comment: It doesn't seem like anything you can do will be ergonomic.  Either you will need to tilt your head down or up. Would your routine let you use single focals when at your computer, and swap to bi- when doing other things?

Answer (score 3):

The only two options you have are removing anything that is already below the monitor, or sitting on a taller chair. As Journey Man mentioned, you could also try a desk with a [adjustable cutout for a monitor](http://www.smartdesks.com/images/instrt-DSR3072.jpg).

You could possibly try and get a [monitor arm](http://ergonomics.ucr.edu/images/Humanscale%20M8%20single.JPG) to raise and lower the screen when you want. This option is likely to cost more than a monitor with an adjustable stand however.

Comment: There's also an older style of table for CRTs that had a little cutout with a lower 'deck' for monitors. Might work here

Answer (score 1):

Other thing that could potentially help is getting a smaller monitor.  A smaller monitor would have the top closer to the surface on which it is sitting.

A third potential option would be to forego the bifocals by adjusting the font settings on the computer to make everything larger (zoomed in).  For example, in Chrome, there's a zoom feature that makes everything bigger.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this problem myself, and also couldn't find a reasonable, commercially available solution. Ultimately I solved it by designing and building a custom monitor stand that lowers a monitor to the correct height and angle for optimum viewing through bifocals or reading glasses.  It is a great help for bifocal/reader wearing computer users whether they use a laptop with a second monitor, or one, two or three desktop monitors.

Enough friends commented on my stands that I ended up re-designing them for low cost production, and put up a KickStarter to get initial production funded.  If you'd like to get the complete story, and consider acquiring a stand for yourself (I named them FocalPoint stands), please visit my Kickstarter: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1562252540/focalpoint-monitor-stand-for-bifocal-users or my website http://www.focalpointstand.com

Thanks for considering my answer!